# Twisted HTTP/TCP Protocols

Tags: python, twisted

I am trying to create a twisted server that would accept an http post request and then write the info of that post request to a tcp connection.  Right now I have just modified the multiple echo server/client given in the tutorial:

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol, Factory
from twisted.internet import reactor


class MultiClientEcho(Protocol):
    def __init__(self, factory):
        self.factory = factory

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.insert(self.factory.id, self)
        self.factory.id += 1
        self.ip = self.transport.getPeer()

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.factory.clients[0].transport.write(data)

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)


class MultiClientEchoFactory(Factory):
    def __init__(self):
        self.clients = []
        self.id = 0

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return MultiClientEcho(self)


reactor.listenTCP(8000, MultiClientEchoFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I've been led to understand that Twisted can handle these kinds of things.  If so, can someone point me in the right direction with some code or a simple example?  I've been hitting my head against the wall on this one for a while.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by "write the info of that post"?  Do you want to write an HTTP proxy that modifies POSTs, or just a debug thing that responds to a POST by pretty-printing the POST's variables in HTML, or some other thing?

Comment: I really just want a server that can handle multiple protocols at once, including http and tcp.  What I meant was to parse the POST response's form data or json object and send that information over a tcp connection.